# How To Override Default SQS Configurations For Spring Cloud AWS Messaging

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-aws

Specifically looking to override the default `AmazonSQSAsync` client in order to ensure that the client is compatible with FIFO queues as mentioned in the version 2.4.2 documentation [here](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.4.2/reference/html/index.html#fifo-queue-support) . Defining a bean in my application in a `@Configuration` class similar to the documentation (as shown below) still results in the warning `AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient that Spring Cloud AWS uses by default to communicate with SQS is not compatible with FIFO queues. Consider registering non-buffered AmazonSQSAsyncClient bean.` Although, requests do seem to work I have not yet been able to determine if the correct `AmazonSQSAsync` client is being used. I'm looking for either a way to adjust my configuration that removes this warning (because my
`AmazonSQSAsync` bean is being used) or way to confirm that the message is actually a red herring. The dependency I'm using is `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` version 2.4.2

```
@Configuration
public class SQSConfig {

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS(@Value("${aws.region}") String awsRegion) {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                .withRegion(awsRegion)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an error with configuration. I had mistakenly left the xml configuration `<aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-listener />` active which was the source of the erroneous SQS client. Removing that xml configuration and including an override of the `amazonSQS` bean (bean name must match exactly) with an instance of `AmazonSQSAsync` solved the issue.